# Vaadin Flow - Create Own Component with StyleSheet "themeFor"

Tags: java, css, themes, vaadin-flow

Hi There I am new to vaadin. I like to have an own component created for whichI like to import its own "local" css stylesheet. I tried to follow the guidelines (here and here) but it is not working. What I am doing wrong? I am using Vaadin v17.0.9. Thank you in advance.

**Issues and Questions**

- The @CssImport for my component seems to be ignored. Is there a way to set the text color to "red"?
- Is there a way to set a default .css stylesheet file for my component which can be overriden?

**Java Classes**

```
@Route("/")
@Theme(value = Lumo.class)
@CssImport(value = "./styles/hello-component.css", themeFor = "hello")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        setSizeFull();
        add(new HelloComponent());
    }
}

@Tag("hello")
public class HelloComponent extends Div {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public HelloComponent() {
        init();
    }
    
    private void init() {
        setSizeFull();
        setText("Test");
    }
}
```

**Stylesheet** "frontend/styles/hello-component.css"

```
:host  {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this new video on YouTube can help: [*Styling Web Components with Shadow DOM: CSS variables, parts, shared styles*](https://youtu.be/Y0uxb4ga44Y)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a Local Style Scope to your custom component, `HelloComponent`, because it doesn't even have a Shadow DOM. Local Style Scopes are relevant for regular Vaadin components (such as a `TextField` or a `Button`) because these components have a Shadow DOM. In your case, `HelloComponent` has to use the global style scope using regular CSS selectors. You can do this in Java code using the component's `getStyle()` method:

```
HelloComponent helloComponent = new HelloComponent();
helloComponent.getStyle().set("color", "red");
```

Or, alternatively, you can import a global style sheet using the `@CssImport` annotation, then in this style sheet, target your `HelloComponent` using the regular CSS selectors. For example, you can add `@CssImport("./shared-styles.css")` to one of your classes, then in `shared-styles.css` place the following style:

```
hello {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to create a custom element with its own shadow DOM, you'll need to create a client-side component for that using Polymer or Lit-element. But even then, the `@CssImport` with `themeFor = "MyCustomElement"` will not work automatically. For that to work, your client-side custom element would also have to implement `ThemableMixin`(https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin). The latter is the necessary ingredient that allows any component (including Vaadin own regular components) to have its shadow DOM stylable using the `@CssImport`.